# Replace unicode characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unicode, replace, sql-update

Is it possible to replace all the occurrences of a given character (expressed in unicode) with another character (expressed in unicode) in a varchar field in PostgreSQL?

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET myfield = regexp_replace(myfield, '\u0050', '\u0060', 'g')
```

But it seems that it really writes the string '\u0060' in the field and not the character corresponding to that code.

Answer (score 13):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation on lexical structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE), you should use `U&` syntax:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET myfield = regexp_replace(myfield, U&'\0050', U&'\0060', 'g')
```

You can also use the PostgreSQL-specific escape-string form `E'\u0050'`. This will work on older versions than the unicode escape form does, but the unicode escape form is preferred for newer versions. This should show what's going on:

```
regress=> SELECT '\u0050', E'\u0050', U&'\0050';
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
 \u0050   | P        | P
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 5):

It should work with the "characters corresponding to that code" unless come client or other layer in the food-chain mangles your code!

Also, use [**`translate()`** or `replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for this simple job. Much faster than `regexp_replace()`. `translate()` is also good for multiple simple replacements at a time.
And avoid **empty updates** with a `WHERE` clause. Much faster yet, and avoids table boat and additional `VACUUM` cost.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    myfield  = translate(myfield, 'P', '`')  -- actual characters
WHERE  myfield <> translate(myfield, 'P', '`');
```

If you keep running into problems, use the encoding [@mvp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190166/939860) provided:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET   myfield =  translate(myfield, U&'\0050', U&'\0060')
WHERE myfield <> translate(myfield, U&'\0050', U&'\0060');
```