# PostgreSQL replace range of unicode chars

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, unicode, replace

I have some problems with characters not allowed in XML-export. The request is simply to remove the invalid characters from the text to ensure corrext export/import of data.

so far, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190078/replace-unicode-characters-in-postgresql) I have an sql statement which replaces one declared Unicode char:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myproperty = replace(myproperty, U&'\UNICODE', '');
```

It removes the specified Unicode from all occurrences inside the defined cell. But I would like to give a bunch of Unicode chars to be replaced, eg. 0x1 - 0xf
Does anybody have an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [TRANSLATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) to remove multiple characters:

```
TRANSLATE(myproperty, 'list of characters', '');
```

Normally it's used to replace characters, but if the replacement string is empty it's removing them.

Edit:

Of course you can also use a regular expression, this allows ranges of characters:

```
regexp_replace(myproperty, '[\u0041-\u0043a]', '', 'g')
```

Adding the `'g'` flag to replace all occurrences...

Comment: thanks @dnoeth, that helps a little. do you know a way to set a range of codes? I tried that out but it does not work (eg. `U&'[\0041-\0043]'`)

Comment: @RuthiRuth: There's no way to specifiy a range in `TRANSLATE`, but there's `REGEXP_REPLACE`. I modify my answer...

Comment: I tried that but then I get only the first occurrence in "myproperty" and not all occurences...

Comment: I got it, I have to set the flag 'g' to replace it with all occurrences. if you could edit your answer @dnoeth I can mark it as right :)

Comment: @RuthiRuth: Thanks, every DBMS has it's own rules regarding regex. Added it to my answer...

Comment: argh, I have to write a compatible code for database 8.4 now, and it always says: `WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal, HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.` so how can I use this method with 8.4? could not find anything to match unicode chars so far :(

Comment: @RuthiRuth: Sorry, I don't have access to a 8.4 system, but according to the official documentation it's the same syntax for Unicode literals...

Comment: This for multiple ranges (\u3000-\u309F]|[\u30A0-\u30FF]|[\u4E00-\u9FFF]|[\uFF00-\uFFEF]