# PostgreSQL - replace all instances of particular character in table columns

Tags: postgresql, unicode, replace, symbols

I have table `article` which contains columns like `title`, `author`, `headline`, `body`, `subheading`, `abstract`, and some more. I'm trying to replace all instances of particular symbol in all aforementioned columns at once (but not in the others) but I must say that working on SQL and databases isn't anything I know much about...

I've found this line here on stackoverflow, however after editing it into what I thought would work I see no effect. I hoped to start with just `title` column to see the results:

```
UPDATE article SET title = replace(title, '<U+2029>', ' ');
```

But it didn't change anything.

Can somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong and what to write in PostgreSQL to get what I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that is a unicode constant, then you can try this:

```
UPDATE article
    SET title = regexp_replace(title, U&'\2029', ' ', 'g');
```

This assumes that 2029 is the *hexadecimal* representation of the character.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190078/replace-unicode-characters-in-postgresql

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me from manually editing a couple of thousand entries! Just one thing: it should be: `...' ', 'g');`, didn't work without apostrophes around g.